# How to view a single Mapbox Vector Tile?

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles

I know of setups that display sets of Mapbox Vector Tiles packaged inside a `.mbtiles` file in a webmap (e.g. http://osm2vectortiles.org/docs/getting-started/ ).

But as part of some experiments I currently have a single Mapbox Vector Tile and need to preview it (as an image) to check its contents.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you use QGIS, there is now a plugin called [Vector Tiles Reader](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/vector_tiles_reader/) which should do what you want:

> Vector tiles reader which supports server connections, MBTiles file
>   and other sources

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS 3.13, you can read the vector tiles directly as a normal layer. Just drag and drop the mbtile/pbf to